# Div that expands only upwards and scrolls at max height

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox, frontend

So I'm writing a frontend with react and I have a chat window that looks like so

```
<div id="outer-wrapper">
    <div className = "chat-window-wrapper">
        <div className="chat-window">
        <!-- chat messages go here -->
        </div>
        <div className="chat-window-textarea"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="element-below">
        <!-- other stuff -->
    </div>
</div>
```

inside of the `chat-window` div I am using react to render messages from an observable array of messages, each message inside of `chat-window` looks like this:

```
    <div>
        {messageStr}
    </div>
```

I calculate the height of the `chat-window-wrapper` div based on the amount of messages in react and it works great, and I have a max height that the outer div can expand to that works great. I'm working on getting the inside of `chat-window-wrapper` to look right

- I need the `chat-window-textarea` to remain anchored to the bottom, currently it sits kind of in the middle of the messages with a lot of empty space below it
- I need `chat-window-wrapper` to only expand upwards, currently if I hit the max height the window starts to expand downwards and the element-below gets pushed off the screen. I want `chat-window` to scroll if `chat-window-wrapper` reaches max height

I'm collaborating on a larger project, so I'm currently treating `outer-wrapper` and `element-below` as a black box, but I can change the css on those elements if absolutely necessary

How would I go about doing this with css?
I have tried a bunch of stuff, and I can post my janky css files if needed, but I think I'm going to have to start from scratch anyway. Any guidance is appreciated even if it's just a small suggestion

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems that you are working on a chat app which show messages from new to old and have a textarea to edit message.  for your question:

1. make `chat-window-textarea` to the bottom: you can use flex layout in the  parent element `chat-widnow-wrapper` and set `flex-direction: column`, set chat-window to take the rest space;
2. make `chat-window-wrapper` to expand upwards: use flex and flex-direction: column-reverse;

the css is below:

```
  .chat-window-wrapper {
    width: 100px; /* for demo */
    border: 1px solid #eaeaea; /* for demo */
    height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column; /* Reverse column to make it expand upwards */
  }

  .chat-window {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
    overflow-y: auto; /* Enable vertical scroll if needed */
    flex: 1;
  }
```

demo: https://codepen.io/nxoglrnh-the-decoder/pen/eYXmWYW